# Output to the console Intelij Idea chess pieces in java

Tags: java, encoding

I'm trying to implement a training task and output chess pieces to the console, but no matter how I change the encoding, the console still shows question marks instead of a chess piece. I will be grateful for your help! i'm using Intelij Idea

```
public class Chess {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("♝");
    }
}
```

and in console i see : ? insread of ♝

Im trying UTF - 8, and many others Encodings, but nothig does work. I'm om 8.1 windows

Comment: The font your console use must support these characters, that it obviously does not. Change the font for it!

Comment: I've been trying, but it doesn't work too

Comment: Does "to the console" mean the console sub-window of the IntelliJ IDEA IDE? Or the Windows terminal? Or what exactly? Make sure that the component that serves as "the console" accepts UTF-8, uses a font that contains glyphs for the chess symbols, and make sure that in your program, System.out uses UTF-8 encoding.